# HTML5 video preload solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a website with some animations. One of them is the logo animation. It's called 'lbv.mp4'. As it has some weight, there's a lag with autoplay, so I decided to show content when it is fully loaded.

The plan is:

- the video is checked for loading
- start the video
- add a class to the page element to trigger the animation
- `setTimeout` for the length of the video which will make `visibility: hidden` for the clip to open a static image underneath.

This is better described in the following code:

```
    video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function () {
    if (video.readyState === 4) {
        video.play();
        $('#page').addClass('transition');
        document.setTimeout(function(){
            video.attr('style', 'visibility: hidden');
        }, 750);
    }
```

The only problem is that I can't get it working neither with pure JS, neither with JQuery. The video isn't loading, the classes aren't given. Tested in Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

So the final question is: 'Is there another to make it easier, or how to fix my solution?'

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. When your video is fully loaded, you hide it ?

Comment: @codename44 After my video is loaded it is played and then hided, after a 0.75s delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event `loadeddata` means :

> The first frame of the media has finished loading.

`readyState === 4` means :

> Enough data is available—and the download rate is high enough—that the media can be played through to the end without interruption.

You have chances that `loadeddata` is triggered but `readyState` is not `4`.
Since `loadeddata` is triggered only once, the video won't ever play.

You should try to add logs to verify this assumption.

What I would try is the following :

- Use `<video>` with `autoplay`
- Listen for the `playing` event on the video to start transition
- Listen for the `ended` event on the video to hide it

Reference for attributes, events and readyState:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Video
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState